# Which version of CXF and spring to use?

Tags: spring, cxf

I am new to both CXF and Spring. 
I want to know which version of CXF and Spring to use to build webservices?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [latest](http://www.springsource.org/download) version of Spring (currently 3.1) and the [latest](http://cxf.apache.org/download.html) version of CXF (currently 2.5.2).